# how can I fill my database records with these strings randomly

Tags: t-sql, insert

my table is like this:

```
[int]
[FullSizeImageName]
[ThumbSizeImageName]
[Title]
[Alt]
[Sort]
[Size]
```

I want to fill [Title] and [Alt] with these strings randomly ["string1","string2","string3","string4"]

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is not a problem you will solve in pure sql. You will write a script that will generate your INSERT statement using a random selection from your list and then execute that INSERT statement. Either that or build out a flat file that has random values where you like and then bulk insert that.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Thanks, ok.
i'll read.

Answer (score 0):

This does not fully work but you might be able to do something with it

SQL is not really built for generating random numbers.

```
declare @T table (id int, val varchar(10));
insert into @T (id, val) values (0, 'one'), (1, 'two'), (2, 'three'), (3, 'four');
select name, abs(convert(int, convert (varbinary(8), NEWID(), 1)))%4 r
     , (select top 1 t.val from @T t where id = abs(convert(int, convert (varbinary(8), NEWID(), 1)))%4) rr 
from sys.all_objects
```